# Javascript add image to div without changing div height and width?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
   <div id="storage-bin-title">
    <div id="storage-bin">
        <div style="z-index:1; width:200px; background-color:black;" id="abc">
            <img src="http://2aek.com/inventory/test/1.png" />
            <img src="http://2aek.com/inventory/test/edit-button.png" id="edit" style="display:none" />
            <img src="http://2aek.com/inventory/test/delete-button.png" id="add" style="display:none;" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#abc").mouseover(function () {
        $("#edit").css({ display: 'inline', position:'relative', left:15, top:-55  });
        $("#add").css({ display: 'inline', position:'relative', left:15, top:-55  });

    });


    $("#abc").mouseout(function () {
        $("#edit").css({ display: 'none'});
        $("#add").css({ display: 'none' });
    });
});
</script>
```

Demo at : http://jsfiddle.net/zac1987/nru11uuo/2/

Problem : When mouseover the div, javascript will add another 2 image into the div, so the div width and heigh expended. How to use css to make the div width and heigh remain the same when the two images are added into it by javascript?

Comment: explanation would be nice..

Comment: @Saar, ok I have added the explanation, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use Javascript for CSS functionality. CSS solution would be better here. You need to position edit/add buttons absolutely relatively to parent container, just adjust bottom and left positions.

```css
#abc {position: relative;}
#abc .btn {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px;
}
#abc #add {left: 30px;}
#abc:hover .btn {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="storage-bin-title">
    <div id="storage-bin">
        <div style="z-index:1; width:200px; background-color:black;" id="abc">
            <img src="http://2aek.com/inventory/test/1.png" />
            <img src="http://2aek.com/inventory/test/edit-button.png" class="btn" id="edit" />
            <img src="http://2aek.com/inventory/test/delete-button.png" class="btn" id="add" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

If the `<div>` has the CSS property `overflow:hidden;`, adding an image shouldn't change the size of the div.